# Jquery ui tabs with Jquery menu aim feature

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to implement Jquery ui tabs with Jquery menu aim feature but it is not working, however it works well with bootstrap. Have any one tried to implement this feature on JQuery vertical ui tabs? pls help my code is as follows.

This is what (http://static.tumblr.com/9hgswys/iNYmj8gfd/new-full.gif) I want to achieve using the Jquery Ui vertical UI tabs.

```
<!-- My code -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
  <script src="js/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/menu-hover-fixes.js"></script> 

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tab_example" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tab_example li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
    $( "#tab_example" ).tabs({
      event: "mouseover"    
    });

   }); 
  </script>

  <style>
  #tab_example{width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;}
  .ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em;background:#DAE9C5; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em;  }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {background:#DAE9C5; clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block;width:100%; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; background:#4F6828;color:#FFFFFF;}
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 0.9em; float: left; width: 40em;background:#DAE9C5}
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="tab_example">
  <ul id="navBar">
    <li data-submenu-id="t1"><a href="#t1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li data-submenu-id="t2"><a href="#t2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li data-submenu-id="t3"><a href="#t3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li data-submenu-id="t4"><a href="#t4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="t1" class="popover">
    <p>This is Tab 1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="t2" class="popover">
    <p>This is Tab 2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="t3" class="popover">
    <p>This is Tab 3 content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="t4" class="popover">
    <p>This is Tab 4 content</p>
  </div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far that makes it easier for us to help you answer your question correctly. Check [how to ask good questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am trying to add a delay using (https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim) feature, while selecting the tabs but it is not working.

Comment: Can someone please help me on this!

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to set a delay in the selection of the tabs when I move the cursor in an oblique fashion, Just like the example here (https://rawgit.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/master/example/example.html) but I want to achieve this using Jquery vertical ui tabs.

Comment: Please find my code here - https://embed.plnkr.co/q52PZEMnCiSO8ZKsUXJM/

Answer (score 0):

Its so easy to do that, you don't have to use all those plugins. Just write down the code and it will work.

I have created a page that looks just exactly like the one you want but I used my own code and not yours and its more easier also.

You use the `jQuery` `.hover` function instead. Here is the [link](http://plunker.stephensangkn.org) to what I have done and you can download the entire tutorial  by clicking the link below the page

Comment: Thank you for your time. The link that you have added still does not support menu aim feature. But thank you so much for your efforts, I did solve this issue by using the following code in the link - http://codepen.io/mattweb/pen/pkvlh